# How to install vue-cli on a server?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-cli

I've searched about installing `vue-cli`.
All of them are installed on the `localhost:8080`.

Is it impossible to install on the server?

I tried to install `vue-cli` on port `8080` at my server
but it was installed on port `8081` instead.

However port `8081` is blocked on my server.

My frame is `Laravel` + `vue.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 2 separate projects then using vue-cli is fine. But laravel comes with vue support out of the box, so you probably don't need vue-cli.

Make sure you add your main js-file to `webpack.mix.js`. For example:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist');

mix.options({ 
  hmrOptions :{
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080'
  }
});
```

This should work with an `app.js` such as this:

```
Add import Vue from 'vue';
import Notification from './components/Notification.vue';
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Notification }
});
```

`npm run dev`  runs webpa

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing it in production mode? If yes, then you probably need to build the vue app first by running `npm run build`. It will generate a `dist` folder, and that's what you need in your laravel app.

Comment: you mean before npm run dev, npm run build first? and changed the port and npm run dev?

Comment: No, npm run build if you're done with development already. And you don't need to have server for it. Just place the contents of your dist folder to your laravel public folder

Comment: I typed 'npm run build' and there is error that ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-3dbef398","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Error loading PostCSS